# What is the current state of curly-brace-substring notation in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax, deprecated

In PHP (5.3 and 5.4, at least) you can select a single character from a string using curly braces.

```
php > $x = 'abc';
php > echo $x{1};
b
```

A [comment in the substr documentation](https://www.php.net/substr#76016) indicates that this syntax is deprecated, but the referenced page no longer actually says that it is. However, I also can't find any documentation (except anecdotal/commentary) on the curly-brace-substring syntax itself.

Since PHP has [a history of un-deprecating things](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php), I can't simply assume that if it was once deprecated it is still deprecated. Is there any evidence to suggest whether this single-character substring notation is current and ongoing? Alternatively, is this syntax officially documented, and if so, where?

Comment: have you tried brackets? ```echo $x[1]```. That's how a string should behave if it's casted as an array of characters. Watch out for non ASCII characters, btw.

Comment: The string documentation says *"PHP 5.5 added support for accessing characters within string literals using [] or {}. "*

Comment: @FelixKling OK, but this works in 5.3.

Comment: Oh I guess, that only meant that `"foo"[0]` is possible from PHP 5.5 on.

Comment: But there is another note: *"Note: Strings may also be accessed using braces, as in `$str{42}`, for the same purpose."*. So... it should be fine to use it. http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr

Comment: Aha! There it is. I kept using the word *curly*, so I didn't see it in my searches. I'd accept that as an answer...

Comment: Personally I would still use square brackets ;-)

Comment: [Hack](http://hacklang.org) seems to only allow the square brackets, in case anyone's interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small note in the [string documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr) saying:

> Note: Strings may also be accessed using braces, as in `$str{42}`, for the same purpose.

So, it seems to be officially supported and not go away anytime soon.